# Weka Logistic IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, weka

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to use the Logistic classifier on my data.

I get this when I run the program.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.Instances.attribute(Instances.java:341)
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingValues.convertInstance(ReplaceMissingValues.java:268)
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingValues.input(ReplaceMissingValues.java:140)
at weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic.distributionForInstance(Logistic.java:791)
at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:70)
at ThreadThing.run(ThreadThing.java:73)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The exact same code that I'm running into the problem with works when I use other classifiers, like NaiveBayes, but when I change this line

```
NaiveBayes theclassifier = new NaiveBayes();
```

to

```
Logistic theclassifier = new Logistic();
```

I get an error when I call

```
theclassifier.classifyInstance(instance);
```

Is this a bug in Weka, or do I need to change what I provide to the Logistic classifier?

UPDATE: The same issue occurs when using IBk, but not RandomForest or DecisionStump.

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11` <-- says it right there. Your Arraylist is size 11 and you're trying to access index 11. Max index is 10

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for the reply. I don't know what ArrayList it means. As you can seem the error says that its from an unknown source. Again,  I didn't even write any code with ArrayList in it. The error is on the last line of code in my post.

Comment: I have faced the same problem, and tracked it down to this issue: this seems to be Weka's `Instance` class if it's initialized as a `SparseInstance`. The `ArrayList` iteration happens when Weka is iterating over a particular instance. This is independent of your code, and very likely a bug in Weka.

Comment: Can you try `theclassifier.classifyInstance(new DenseInstance(instance));` ? In my case, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I witnessed the same error while using a Logistic classifier. The problem was that **I applied a filter** to the data which I used to train the classifier. The error disappeared when I **applied the same filter** to the instances I classified.
In my case it was a simple `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove` Filter. I used it to remove an attribute from the training data.

From a high level perspective it is somewhat unclear why the classifier breaks after seeing less attributes during training. Anyway - I guess it is important to make sure that the training data has the exact same structure as the data to be classified.